# Should I use Pylons or Pyramid?

Tags: python, pylons, pyramid

I was planning to move from Django to Pylons, but then I bumped into Pyramid.

What are the differences between Pylons and Pyramid?

I read some text in [PylonsBook](http://pylonsbook.com), which currently covers Pylons 0.9.7, and wonder if it is a to start for Pylons and Pyramid.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Pylons isn't being "cancelled", and it will continue to receive updates. That said, the "future" per se is in Pyramid. On the mailing list is has been referred to as Pylons 2.0. It is fully tested and better documented than Pylons 1.0, so you might as well jump aboard if you're fresh.

Pyramid is essentially the merger of Pylons and Repoze.bfg.  Read more about this on the [pylons-devel](http://groups.google.com/group/pylons-devel?lnk=srg) email list.

Especially, in [this](http://groups.google.com/group/pylons-discuss/browse_thread/thread/97faa18a3429a28e) introductory email. If you have deeper questions, hang out in the #pylons, #pyramid, or #repoze irc (freenode) channels.

Comment: clarification: "better documented" == it has "full documentation" http://docs.pylonshq.com/faq/pyramid.html#what-do-you-mean-by-documented

Comment: I have taken a quick look and by the look of it Pylons is much better. This is one step backward for Pylons :-(

Comment: @jpartogi Are you sure? Did you take a look at this: http://docs.pylonshq.com/pyramid/dev/index.html

Comment: Yeah. It looks like Pyramid is more like django than Pylons :-( I kinda like Pylons architecture.

Comment: @jpartogi yes i it looks like django and i hate that

Comment: @Lennart: "Pyramid was inspired by Zope, Pylons (version 1.0) and Django. As a result, Pyramid borrows several
concepts and features from each, combining them into a unique web framework." - Pyramid documentation

Comment: @Eric Mickelsen: Which answers the question in exactly no way at all. OK, of course it is a bit like Django. They are after all both web frameworks.:)

Comment: @Lennart: True, it doesn't answer your question, but it directly contradicts your assertion.  I never claimed to be helpful!  :-)

Comment: Fair enough, even if I don't agree it contradicts the assertion, as its "looks like" vs "has looked at". :)

Comment: It has borrowed from Django the awesome principle of documenting everything, that shoulnd't be a blocker :-)

Answer (score 19):

You want to go with Pyramid most probably. It may seem like it's a more complicated system, but it's actually much cleaner and very intuitive. Furthermore, the documentation for the project is simply awesome and in my opinion, even better then the django project which is well known for it's documentation.

That does not make it "like django" however. It is still lightly coupled and you can use whatever template, database, form, session management system, etc that you like.

It's worth noting that Pyramid is a base framework and Pylons is being built on top of it.

Comment: So What is the differences between pylons and pyramid if i moved to pyramids

Comment: It's generally faster, easier to understand, better supported, much better docs etc. It also feels closer to 'bare metal' which is useful at times. Furthermore, the code is simply easier to understand and IMO less 'magical'. It can seem difficult at first but once you read the docs it really makes total sense.

Comment: If by Pylons you are referring to the framework, you are wrong. Pylons will not be receiving any feature updates.

Comment: That's some serious kudos for the docs, if you honestly believe they are better than those of Django. I say this because of the praise I often hear of the Django docs.

Answer (score 10):

If you plan to start new project, migrate or just to learn framework I recommend to use Pyramid.

Pylons will stop it's development.
Meanwhile Pyramid is a continuation of Pylons. Thus, it's code is stable. It includes most features from Pylons, adds some new usefull features.

Comment: So pylons will cancelled ??? and is there a tutorial for pyramid or it will be after final release of pyramid 1.0

Comment: About Pylons framework and Pylons project: http://docs.pylonshq.com/faq/pylonsproject.html. Will be usefull excellent Pyramid docs: http://docs.pylonshq.com/pyramid/dev/index.html.